# HTML Form - telephone rel value wont disappear on focus

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Hi I have a html form and I have some javascript that runs each time you focus on the input field the rel value disappears, however it is working on all the input types except for telephone and Im not sure what Ive done wrong.

The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select.fancyselect').fancySelect();

    $('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=phone], input[type=url], textarea,').focus(function(){ 
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('rel')) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=phone], input[type=url], textarea').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('rel'));
        } 
    });
```

the html for the tel form field is:

```
<div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="field-phone">Phone Number:<br /> <em>(Optional)</em></label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number" name="field-phone" id="field-phone" value="<?= $_POST['field-phone']; ?>" rel="Phone number here...">
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

I am using bootstrap aswell and I am finding that this problem only occurs in firefox not chrome or safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == '<?= $_POST['field-phone']; ?>') { this.value = ''; }" value="<?= $_POST['field-phone']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a CSS selector `input[type=phone]` which refers to `<input type='phone'/>` which you do not have. You're using `<input type='number'/>` so you need to use the CSS selector `input[type='number']`.

Comment: I know even though I changed it to input[type='number'] it didnt work.